# BigQuery: Multiple SQL rows merge into single row if the row content is the same

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Using BigQuery, I would like to merge multiple rows into a single row if the row content matches other rows. For example

```
ColumnA  | ColumnB
 ABC      | DEF
 DEF      | GHI
 DEF      | 123
 XYZ      | JKL
```

Result:

```
 Column C
ABC, DEF, GHI, 123
```

Comment: not clear what the logic of expected output. please explain in details

Comment: So you want to select `distinct` values into a comma separated string? Not sure about bigquery, but TSQL would use `STUFF` for that, with the values selected `FOR XML PATH`

Comment: looks like provided output does not support idea of just distinct values - XYZ and JKL are not there for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Using the Standard SQL for BigQuery you can use the STRING_AGG function (click [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators) for more information about the function) and aggregate all the rows in one column into a single string with the values separated by a comma.
In your case, you could select the distinct values from columnA and columnB and add them in one column:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT columnA AS example
FROM (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT columnA
  FROM
    “TABLE_NAME”
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    DISTINCT columnB
  FROM
    “TABLE_NAME”)
```

Afterwards you can use the STRING_AGG to aggregate the distinct values from the previous select into one single row:

```
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(example) AS columnC
FROM (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT A AS example
  FROM (
    SELECT
      DISTINCT A
    FROM
      “TABLE_NAME”
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      DISTINCT columnB
    FROM
      “TABLE_NAME”))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below BigQuery Script

```
DECLARE rows_count, run_away_stop INT64 DEFAULT 0;

CREATE TEMP TABLE ttt AS WITH input AS (
  SELECT 'ABC' ColumnA, 'DEF' ColumnB UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEF', 'GHI' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEF', '123' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'XYZ', 'JKL' 
)
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT val FROM UNNEST([ColumnA, ColumnB]) val ORDER BY val ) arr FROM input;

LOOP
  SET (run_away_stop, rows_count) = (SELECT AS STRUCT run_away_stop + 1, COUNT(1) FROM ttt);

  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE ttt AS
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(arr) arr FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(arr) val ORDER BY val) arr
    FROM (
      SELECT ANY_VALUE(arr1) arr1, ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(arr) arr    
      FROM (
        SELECT t1.arr arr1, t2.arr arr2, ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(ARRAY_CONCAT( t1.arr, t2.arr)) val ORDER BY val) arr 
        FROM ttt t1, ttt t2 
        WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(t1.arr) val JOIN UNNEST(t2.arr) val USING(val)) > 0
      ) GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', arr1)
    )
  ) GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', arr);

  IF (rows_count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ttt) AND run_away_stop > 1) OR run_away_stop > 10 THEN BREAK; END IF;
END LOOP;

SELECT FORMAT('%t', arr) merged_values FROM ttt;
```

with output

```
Row merged_values 
1   [JKL, XYZ]   
2   [123, ABC, DEF, GHI]
```